# What is the best way to load a large folder of files into Julia to compare the columns of each file?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia, data-analysis

New to Julia and programming in general so this is a two part question. Suppose I have a Folder with 3,000 CSV files. Each file is roughly 7,000 x 7. (The number of rows may vary from file to file but the number of columns is constant.) I am trying to read each of these files into an 3000 x N x M tensor or other data structure in julia to compare the outputs by column. (This would mostly involve comparing the sum of the lags in each column vector of each file)

**Question 1: What is the most efficient data structure to parse through this data?** I would essentially be calculating the max of the sum of the lags of each column for all files.  I've been told by a more experienced user that I should be using NamedArrays for this.  I was wondering if anyone could provide some insights as to why?  Would DataFrames be able to perform similar calculations?

**Question 2: Is there an efficient way to read all these files into named arrays?** I can read these files into Dataframes with Glob using the following code.

```
Folder="/Users/Desktop/Data"  
Files=glob("*.csv", Folder) 
df=DataFrame.(CSV.File.(Files))
```

But I don't know how to read it into NamedArrays directly.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is it going to be necessary to load more than one file at a time, or could you just create a DataFrame where each row is a summary of that file's lag values, and process that data?

Comment: I suppose the latter might work if that would be more efficient but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that so any tips would be appreciated.  I basically want to calculate the column lags of each individual csv file and then organize them from max to min.

Comment: If all you need is the overall minimum and overall maximum, you could create a dataframe where the first column was a source file name, the next column a the file's lag minimum, the next column a file maximum, and so forth (so you might need two new columns for every column in the source files, one for each lag min and lag max). This would work as long as you don't need the actual data in the files beyond their lag min and lag max.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I populate the columns?  Can I calculate the columns lag directly from the csv?

Comment: Look at TimeSeries.jl, and you might want the diff function defined there

Comment: thanks! is there a function like TimeSeries that works directly on DataFrames? Or will i have to convert each to matrix or named array?

Comment: https://juliastats.org/TimeSeries.jl/stable/tables/#DataFrame-to-TimeArray-1 shows the conversion